# getActivity is null in Facebook graph request callback

Tags: android, facebook

I have an issue with Facebook graph request callback. in some devices getActivity is null.This code is executing in a fragment is that causing this issue ?.Please help me to fix it .

```
GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                                         new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() 
 {

     @Override
     public void onCompleted(JSONObject object, GraphResponse response)
      {
          //here getActivity() is null

      }
});
```

Comment: have you tried getApplicationContext() instead? And why would you use App.Toast instead of using Toast.makeText(context,string,int).show();?

Comment: @askarcali I wonder if *loginResult.getAccessToken()* returns a valid token? can you please log that and see what you get. It could happen that loginResult.getAccessToken() do not return access token since it has to be deserialized from disk async by when GraphRequest.newMeRequest gets executed without one.

Comment: yeah it is working fine

Comment: getActivity() is null

Comment: Maybe because onDetach() of the fragment gets called before you GraphRequest is completed, so either you use getApplicationContext() or assign member variable to context as in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

keep activity reference when onAttach is called (in your fragment) and use the activity reference wherever needed:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        mContext = context;
    }
```

This happened when you call getActivity() in another thread that finished after the fragment has been removed. Like in case of calling getActivity() (ex. for a Toast) when an HTTP request finished (in onResponse for example).

Comment: GraphRequest callback is not in other thread right.after executing the background thread only this callback will execute

Comment: onAttach(Activity activity) is deprecated use onAttach(Context context)

Comment: still i am not clear why this is happening.surely GraphRequest on complete is not background thread i guess

Comment: i already fixed this issue but i just want to know why this is happening that is why i posted question

Comment: I understand you want to know the reason, I added a comment under your question, but as I don't have your full code and how did you created the fragment and what type of fragment etc. I can't give you a specific answer, you can check this Google search results for the same question and update us with which reason related to your case: https://www.google.com.eg/?gws_rd=ssl#q=android+getactivity+returns+null+in+fragment

Comment: this is normal fragment android.support.v4.app.Fragment  and i implemented by using fb documentation

Comment: Then you should use getSupportActivity() not getActivity() ... Let me know the result.